# Generic type as a constructor parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, dao

I have a **generic dao interface** implemented like this:

```
public interface GenericDao<T extends AbstractEntity>
```

and **AbstractHibernateDao class**:

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao<T extends AbstractEntity> implements GenericDao<T>
```

I'm trying to make **generic table model** like this:

```
public class EntityTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

private GenericDao<AbstractEntity> dao;

public EntityTableModel(GenericDao<AbstractEntity> dao, String[] columnLabels) {
    super(columnLabels, 0);
    this.dao = dao;
}
```

The way I tried to **pass a parameter** looks like this:

```
table.setModel(new EntityTableModel(new SomeEntityHibernateDao(),columns));enter code here
```

And code for **SomeEntityHibernateDao** looks like this:

```
public class SomeEntityHibernateDao extends AbstractHibernateDao<SomeEntity> implements
    SomeEntityDao
```

SomeEntity extends AbstractEntity and SomeEntityDao is interface which extends GenericDao interface.

Can somebody explain to me why this isn't working? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GenericDao<SomeSpecificEntity>` is not the same as `GenericDao<AbstractEntity>`.

Instead, you should allow subclasses:

```
GenericDao<? extends AbstractEntity>
```

You will not be able to call any methods on it that accept `T` as a parameter, since you don't know what `T` is.

Alternatively, you could make the entire TableModel class generic, and accept a `GenericDao<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I used GenericDao<T> as you suggested.